# Differential-Geometry question- Curve Theory

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $r(s)$ be a curve parametrized by the natural parameter $s$  and for its curvature $k$ and torsion $t$ the following condition applies:

$$k(s),t(s)\neq 0 $$ for every $s$.

Prove that the curve lays in the sphere $\iff$ the following is satisfied:

$${\tau\over k}={d\over ds}({{dk / ds}\over \tau k^2})$$

This question keeps coming up on the test year after year at the university , and none have been able to complete it. Help is much appreciated..

Comment: Should this be an equality?

Comment: But of course...

Comment: Then why not edit the question accordingly?

Comment: Sorry for the imprecision.

Comment: No problem : ) ${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Known result : If $a$ is parametrized by arc-length, then $$
t'=kn,\ n'=-kt-\tau b,\ b'=\tau n $$

(2) Let $$ C = a +\frac{n}{k} + \frac{k'}{\tau k^2} b $$ Then $$
C'=0$$ That is $C$ is a constant vector. In further, $$ \frac{d}{ds}
|a-C|^2 = \bigg( \frac{1}{k^2} + \bigg(\frac{k'}{\tau k^2 }\bigg)^2
\bigg)'  =0 $$